# AngularJS - Expanding Overall Width of ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to build a grid created by AngularJS's ng-grid module that will extend across the width of the webpage.  However, when I create the grid, by default it only extends roughly 1/2 of the way across the page.  Increasing the width of columns only results in columns being cut off instead of expanding the overall grid.  I can't find any online documentation on how to expand the width of grids so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a grid style.

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 300px
}
```

And then apply it to the HTML

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
```